# Join two tables with two columns SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables that I would like to join together. One is a table with various bits of information and one is a dimension view, a definitions table of sorts. The table with the desired information looks like this

```
VISIT ID | ATN_DR_NO | ADM_DR_NO |...
12345678 | 987654    | 123456    |...
```

Where the ATN_DR_NO is the Attending Doctor id number and the ADM_DR_NO is the admitting Doctor id. I have a second table that has the Doctor ID numbers and their corresponding names like so

```
src_prct_no | pract_rpt_name | ...
987654      | Dr. A          | ...
123456      | Dr. B          | ...
...
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to obtain a results in a table where I have the following

```
VISIT ID | ATN_DR_NO | ATN DR NAME | ADM_DR_NO | ADM DR NAME
12345678 | 987654    | DR. A       | 123456    | DR. B
```

I don't know how to join on multiple columns.

Here is the query I am working with in whole:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
-- VARIABLE DECLARATION AND INITIALIZATION
DECLARE @SD DATETIME;
DECLARE @ED DATETIME;
SET @SD = '2014-01-01';
SET @ED = '2014-02-01';

/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
THIS QUERY WILL GET ALL THE FRONT END INFORMATION REQUIRED FOR HOSIM
AND INSERT IT INTO A TABLE THAT WILL GET MATCHED UP WITH THE DISCHARGE
ORDERS TABLE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
START OF QUERY 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
-- TABLE DECLARATION
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (
    [ENCOUNTER ID]               VARCHAR(200)
    , /*NEW*/MRN                 VARCHAR(20)    
    , /*NEW*/DOB                 DATETIME
    , /*NEW*/GENDER              VARCHAR(10)
    , FINANCIALCLASSORIG         VARCHAR(200)
    , [ADMIT DATE]               DATE
    , [ADMIT TIME]               TIME
    , [ADMIT FROM]               VARCHAR(200)
    , [DISCHARGE DATE]           DATE
    , [DISCHARGE TIME]           TIME
    , /*TEST*/[ADMITTING MD NO]  VARCHAR(200)
    , /*TEST*/[ADMITTING MD]     VARCHAR(200)
    , /*TEST*/[ATTENDING MD NO]  VARCHAR(200)
    , /*TEST*/[ADTTENDING MD]    VARCHAR(200)
    , [MS DRG]                   VARCHAR(200)
    , LOS                        VARCHAR(20)
    , [ADMIT PATIENT STATUS]     VARCHAR (10)
    , [DISCHARGE PATIENT STATUS] VARCHAR(10)
    , [DISCHARGE DISPOSITION]    VARCHAR (200)
    , [DISCHARGE UNIT]           VARCHAR (200)
)
-- WHAT GETS INSERTED INTO @T1
INSERT INTO @T1
SELECT
A.[VISIT ID]
, A.MRN
, A.DOB
, A.GENDER
, A.FINANCIALCLASSORIG
, A.[ADMIT DATE]
, A.[ADMIT TIME]
, A.[ADMIT FROM]
, A.[DISCHARGE DATE]
, A.[DISCHARGE TIME]
, A.[ADMITTING DR NO]
, A.[ADMITTING DR]
, A.[ATTENDING DR NO]
, A.[ATTENDING DR]
, A.[MS DRG]
, A.LOS
, A.[ADMIT PATIENT STATUS]
, A.[DISCHARGE PATIENT STATUS]
, A.[DISCHARGE DISPOSITION]
, A.[DISCHARGE UNIT]
-- END @T1 INSERT SELECTION

-- WHERE IT ALL COMES FROM
-- COLUMN SELECTION
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PAV.PtNo_Num        AS [VISIT ID]
    , /*NEW*/PAV.Med_Rec_No             AS MRN
    , /*NEW*/PAV.Pt_Birthdate           AS DOB
    , /*NEW*/PAV.Pt_Sex                 AS GENDER
    , PD.pyr_name                       AS [FinancialClassOrig]
    , CAST(PAV.Adm_Date AS DATE)        AS [ADMIT DATE]
    , CAST(PAV.vst_start_dtime AS TIME) AS [ADMIT TIME]
    , PAV.Adm_Source                    AS [ADMIT FROM]
    , CAST(PAV.Dsch_Date AS DATE)       AS [DISCHARGE DATE]
    , CAST(PAV.Dsch_DTime AS TIME)      AS [DISCHARGE TIME]
    , /*TEST*/PAV.Adm_Dr_No             AS [ADMITTING DR NO]
    , /*TEST*/PDV.pract_rpt_name        AS [ADMITTING DR]
    , /*TEST*/PAV.Atn_Dr_No             AS [ATTENDING DR NO]
    , /*TEST*/PDV.pract_rpt_name        AS [ATTENDING DR]
    , PAV.drg_no                        AS [MS DRG]
    , PAV.Days_Stay                     AS [LOS]
    , 'I'                               AS [ADMIT PATIENT STATUS]
    , 'I'                               AS [DISCHARGE PATIENT STATUS]
    , DDM.dsch_disp_desc                AS [DISCHARGE DISPOSITION]
    , VR.ward_cd                        AS [DISCHARGE UNIT]

    -- FROM DB(S)
    FROM smsdss.BMH_PLM_PtAcct_V PAV
         JOIN smsdss.pract_dim_v PDV
         ON PAV.Adm_Dr_No = PDV.src_pract_no
         /*TEST*/AND PAV.Atn_Dr_No = PDV.src_pract_no
         JOIN smsdss.pyr_dim PD
         ON PAV.Pyr1_Co_Plan_Cd = PD.pyr_cd
         JOIN smsmir.vst_rpt VR
         ON PAV.PtNo_Num = VR.acct_no
         JOIN smsdss.dsch_disp_mstr DDM
         ON VR.dsch_disp = DDM.dsch_disp

    -- FILTER(S)
    WHERE PAV.Dsch_Date >= @SD 
    AND PAV.Dsch_Date < @ED
    AND PAV.Plm_Pt_Acct_Type = 'I'
    AND PAV.PtNo_Num < '20000000'
    AND PDV.src_spclty_cd = 'HOSIM'
    AND PD.orgz_cd = 'S0X0'
    AND PD.pyr_name != '?'
) A

SELECT * FROM @T1
```

Do you think I should just create variables like `@ADM_DR` and `@ATN_DR` and in the `WHERE` clause set them equal to a select statement that would get them?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You join back into the table again, so it looks as though you're FROMing that same table twice (one for the attending doctor lookup, one for the admitting doctor lookup).

```
SELECT a.doc_name as attending_name, 
       b.somefield, 
       a2.doc_name as admitting_name

FROM doctors a, 
     someothertable b, 
     doctors a2

WHERE a.doc_id = b.attending_doc_id
  AND a2.doc_id = b.admitting_doc_id
  AND b.record_id = <whatever>
```

and your inner join for a targets the first doctor, the join for a2 targets the second doctor.

Pardon the pseudo-code, but I think you get the idea.   You'll notice that a and a2 are both getting the doc_name field from the doctors table, but they're joined to the different IDs off the b table.

Comment: Thank you Jason, I was going to do it I think a bit more complicated way and make a variable, which I am glad I did not do.

Comment: I modified the pseudo-code a bit more so it's easier to read.   Glad I could help.