# Two table SQL double join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, `sections` and `articles`.  Originally it was a one-to-many relationship, therefore `articles` has a `sectionID` column.  Then one day it was decided to allow each article to belong to two sections.  Rather than making another 'articles-in-section' table, I opted to not deal with refactoring the data, and I just added an `additionalSectionID` column onto the `articles` table.  Now I have a problem.

I want to show all the articles associated with a given section, whether as its primary or secondary section.  Essentially, I'm looking for some sort of double join between two tables.

These two questions have answers to the same issue - [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768480/join-two-tables-with-two-columns-sql-server-2008-r2),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598409/sequelize-double-joining-table-on-two-ids), but with a different db server.  Is there are a way to do this in PHP/MySQL?

Tables' structure is basically like this:

```
-- SECTIONS:
id   title   description   moderatorID   url

-- ARTICLES: 
id   title   shortDesc     fullText      photo   sectionID   additionalSectionID
```

Comment: Sounds like a good time to complete that refactor.

Comment: I'm with you, put who's going to put up the `$` for it? :)

Comment: It's probably achievable with a simple `UNION`. Please post a sample from the two tables, together with a sample of what you would expect the query output to look like.

Comment: @jegesh Why do you think it will be that much more time consuming to build a proper many-to-many join table than to implement a potentially poorly performing query?  In either case, you are going to need to change the queries in your application and creating the new table should take all of about 10 minutes.

Comment: @MikeBrant The problem is that the site was originally written (not by me) with no framework, in *spaghetti*.  Changing the db structure in that way would mean hunting down 10+ places in the code and changing each one, each time with a possibility for typos or other errors.  The site owner has promised to go through with a grand refactoring/overhaul of the awful code, but until then...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Added summary of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below.

```
SELECT s.*, a.*
FROM sections s
LEFT JOIN articles a
ON s.id = a.sectionID
OR s.id = a.additionalSectionID
WHERE s.title = 'My Section';
```

Comment: Is this valid syntax for MySQL?  I've never seen an `OR` with `ON` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You might try two inner joins on separate table aliases, along the lines of:

```
SELECT 
*,
s1.section_name AS sectionA, 
s2.section_name AS sectionB
FROM articles    
    INNER JOIN sections s1 ON articles.sectionID = s1.sectionID
    INNER JOIN sections s2 ON articles.additionalSectionID = s2.sectionID
```

Comment: I'll try this out in the next few days and let you know